# discord.js is there a way to get the id of a channel into a variable outside of the .then() when creating a new channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

My problem is that i am making a channel and i want to get the id of the channel into a variable outside of the `message.guild.channels.create()` but the problem is all ways i know to do this don't work as the `channelId` variable ends up as `undefined` is there any possible way i can have it not be undefined?

```
var channelId; // the variable i want the id to be in

            message.guild.channels.create('Lobby-' + lobbyCount, {
                type: 'text',
                parent: '868148689644957726'
            }).then(channel => {
                channelId = channel.id; // the id i want to get
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `await` instead `.then()`

```
const channel = await message.guild.channels.create('Lobby-' + lobbyCount, {
  type: 'text',
  parent: '868148689644957726'
})
channelId = channel.id
```

note that in order to use `await`, the function that has the above code needs to be `async` as `async function funcName(){}`

Comment: The function it is in is a part of a module.exports. And it doesn't seam to work with the async or i am doing something wrong. EDIT: i forgot to remove the .then() from it, it works now